# animated highlighting of table row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to change (animated) the color of the table row if the mouse is over it. Could you help me to do this? Thanks.

```
td{width:200px;text-align:center; background-color:gray;}


$('tr').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "gray" }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXejr/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr').mouseover(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "#666" }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MtF6E/

Table rows don't respond to background color, so you change the background of the `td`s inside, instead. And for some reason it doesn't like "gray" at all. Thought that was actually a valid CSS color name, but apparently not. I used "#666" instead and it worked fine. I also introduced `stop(true, true)`. That will stop any in progress animation on the element, so the current one can go ahead. It leads to a smoother look and response.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr ").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "Red" }, 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "White" }, 1000);
    }
);
```

use [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to prevent the animation from occurring if the mouse is hovered frequently

http://jsfiddle.net/NXejr/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr td').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#444');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jp4AP/

Answer (score 0):

Try using hover instead of mouseover and mouseout:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ "background-color" : "red" }, 1000);
},
function () {
    $(this).animate({ "background-color" : "gray" }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

You're animating the color of `tr`, but this is over-ridden by your `td` styling.

Change to

```
$('tr').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('td').animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
});
```

Will get the `mouseover` working.

For some reason jQuery isn't liking `gray` in the `mouseout` function. Not sure why that is, but it will work if you change to for example

```
$('tr').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('td').animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "#aaa" }, 1000);
});
```

I also prefer using the `hover` solution a couple of the other suggested, but they didn't address these issues